# Recursion to check if a String equals another string

Tags: java, string, recursion

my current code returns the output:

```
true
Expected: true

false
Expected: true

false
Expected: true

false
Expected: false

false
Expected: false
```

So there's an issue with my logic that i'm not seeing

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println(find("",""));
    System.out.println("Expected: true\n");

    System.out.println(find("Mitten","Mit"));
    System.out.println("Expected: true\n");
    System.out.println(find("I love my CS courses!"," CS"));
    System.out.println("Expected: true\n");
    System.out.println(find("","Cookies."));
    System.out.println("Expected: false\n");
    System.out.println(find("Java","Python"));
    System.out.println("Expected: false\n");


}
public static boolean find(String text, String str)
{

    boolean found = false;
    if(text.length() == 0 && str.length() == 0)
    {
        found = true;
        return found; 
    }
    if(text.length() == 0 || str.length() == 0)
    {
        return found; 
    }
    if(str.length() > text.length())
    {
        return found;
    }
    if(str.equals(text.substring(0,str.length()-1))) 
    {
        found = true;   
    }
    else
    {
        text = text.substring(1);
        find(text, str);
    }
    return found;
}
```

please help

Comment: You're defining `found` on each recursion call.

Comment: You title says *"if a String **equals** another string"*, but your code says that you expect `true` when comparing `Mitten` and `Mit`, and they are definitely **not** equal. So, what is it you really want the method to do?

Comment: You should get rid of the `found` variable. Just return `true` or `false` directly, or the value from the recursive call, which you by-the-way are **not** doing right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see an issue with this statement

```
if(str.equals(text.substring(0,str.length()-1)))
```

Since the second index of `substring` is exclusive, it should be

```
if(str.equals(text.substring(0,str.length())))
```

in order to compare `str` to the first `str.length` characters of `text`.

Of course you can use `text.contains(str)` or `text.startsWith(str)` and eliminate some of your code, but perhaps that's not part of the exercise requirements.

Beside that issue, when you make a recursive call, you should usually do something with the value returned by that call :

```
found = find(text, str);
```

otherwise, why make the recursive call in the first place? (unless it has side effects of mutating the objects passed as parameters to the recursive call, which it does not in your case)

Comment: Thanks! that corrected the output for the 3rd test but i'm still getting false when expected true for the 4th test. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3185727 one more mistake is that you're not assigning the return value of your recursive call, it should be `found = find(text, str);`

Comment: Bingo! Thanks all!